# Update the gh-pages branch with master branch

Tags: git, github, markdown

I'm trying to update the `gh-pages` branch with the `master` branch, but I can't push the code to `gh-pages`.
I want to update `gh-pages` branch because that's the one rendering in my GitHub website.

I think I mixed up the command. Every time I search for solution I type it.

What I need to do to or what command I need to update the gh-pages from the master branch?

Here is my terminal in VS Code:

[image: git status]

[image: git rebase]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can change the [publication source at anytime](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#choosing-a-publishing-source). gh-pages does not have to be the one rendering your GitHub site.

Second, do a `git branch -avv` to check if each branch has an associated branch with the same name.
I have the impression `gh-pages` is associated with `maste` (hence the invalid name, instead of `master`)

I would not recommend mixing up names between local and remote branches.